# Supplying distributable app to client that they can deploy through Airwatch

Tags: mobile, client, licensing, mdm, airwatch

I have created an app in Adobe Flash CC and have been able to have the client distribute the app to their staff (this is intended for in-house use only) through Airwatch.

This has been done by adding their UDIDs to my Developer account's 'beta tester' list, however this is obviously cumbersome and I now need to be able to supply them with an ipa that they can deploy at will.

I've honestly tried to find the answer on these forums, but my head is now bursting with permutations of licensing options, profiles, etc.

If I upgrade to an Enterprise licence will I then be able to give them a file they can then use, or will I still require certificates from the client?

Answer (score 0):

The AirWatch Console allows the admin to deploy internal, public and purchased apps to all devices of the organization. So you can either give your application file to the admin or publish your app on the store of the OS used by the organization.